# How to improve performance for the web without freezing or lagging when making multiple API calls at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, api, performance

Currently I am working on a function that exports components to PDFs

`

```
import { PDFExport } from "@progress/kendo-react-pdf";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "hooks";
import { get } from "lodash";
import { ManagerGeotechnicalDetail } from "pages/GeotechnicalDetail";
import PointDetail from "pages/PointDetail";
import DataChilAnalyticsDetails from "pages/Project/DataChildAnalyticsDetails";
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { getListPoints } from "store/actions/datamap";
import { ETypeParent } from "../../state/reducer";

interface Props {
  dataOverview: any[];
  title: string;
  idButton: string;
}

const DownloadPDF: FC<Props> = ({ dataOverview, title, idButton }) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const [dataPointsSelected, projectState] = useAppSelector((state) => [
    state.datamap.data,
    state.project.project,
  ]);
  const pdfExportComponent = useRef<PDFExport>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (projectState.projectnumber) {
      dispatch(
        getListPoints(
          get(projectState, "bounds"),
          projectState,
          dataPointsSelected.dataSummaryPoints
        )
      );
    }
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [projectState]);

  const renderUIPDF = (data) => {
    switch (data.typeChild) {
      case ETypeParent.RAW_DATA:
        return (
          <PointDetail
            match={{
              params: {
                idpoint: data.pointid,
                id: projectState.projectid,
                isHideForExport: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      case ETypeParent.ASSIGNING_GEOLOGICAL_UNITS:
        return (
          <ManagerGeotechnicalDetail
            match={{
              params: {
                idpointGeotechnical: data.pointid,
                id: projectState.projectid,
                isHideForExport: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      case ETypeParent.DATA_ANALYTICSANALYTICS:
        return (
          <DataChilAnalyticsDetails
            match={{
              params: {
                idDataChildAnalytics: data.childanalysisid,
                id: projectState.projectid,
                isHideForExport: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

    return (
    <div>
      <div className="example-config">
        <button
          id={idButton}
          className="btn btn-success mt-2 me-4 k-button k-button-md k-rounded-md k-button-solid k-button-solid-base"
          onClick={() => {
            if (pdfExportComponent.current) {
              pdfExportComponent.current.save();
            }
          }}
          disabled={title.length === 0}
        >
          Export PDF
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="hide-ui">
        <PDFExport
          paperSize="A3"
          forcePageBreak=".page-break"
          landscape={true}
          ref={pdfExportComponent}
          fileName={title}
          title={title}
          scale={0.6}
          margin={{
            top: "0.75cm",
            left: "3.6cm",
            right: "3.6cm",
            bottom: "0.75cm",
          }}
        >
          {dataOverview &&
            dataOverview.map((data, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  width: "1620px",
                }}
              >
                {renderUIPDF(data)}
                {index !== dataOverview.length - 1 && (
                  <div className="page-break" />
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
        </PDFExport>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DownloadPDF;
```

`

The problem I am facing now is when the dataOverview list has many objects, it will map the data to the components in renderUIPDF then I will call multiple APIs at the same time in those components.
At that time, there will be lag or website freeze :(

So is there any way I can improve the performance of my website without lag, freeze when calling too many APIs at once, the number can be up to more than 100 APIs at once?

Comment: maybe move the data fetching to your backend instead of fetching it all from your client?

Comment: Thank you, @KevinYobeth!
I also tried to think about the way you said but it's hard because in BE I also have to calculate a lot of things if I call all these APIs in one.